# Raspberry PI 3 A+ x5 Cluster PSU Needed Recommendation

Tags: power, power-management, cluster, pi-3a+

I plan to make this x5-x6 RPI 3 A+ cluster but I am no sure what USB Charger to use. I would really prefer something with 5-6 ports. I know the spec for output are 5V/2.5A and I plan to use it in combination of an USB device that uses 5V/0.5A so that would be x5.

I get that I would need something like 15 A (3 A per port) with 75 W in total. All that said, I am not sure if the PIs really use 2.5 A because I would be just use them as proxies(in my opinion that wouldn't load it up excessively).

As for micro USB cables I thought about Volutz Equilibrium(19 AWG Power). On the last note I know it wont be cheap but I would really like to know what are your opinions about this.

Comment: *"I am no sure what USB Charger to use"* -> **Don't** use a USB charger: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106117/5538 Unless of course in a month you want to be yet another person asking why a brand new 5A USB C etc. *charger* still triggers low voltage warnings even when powering a single Pi.  Or you could get lucky.  Or you could do the smart thing and use an actual *power supply*.

Answer (score -1):

If you are okay with soldering a micro-PSU would be a good option. Probably more efficient than a few wall adapters.

Answer (score -1):

Your system need a lot of ampere to function. The USB charger your are searching for may not be found.Instaed you can fetch a SMPS . A good quality SMPS has the abilty to release a lot of power. Mine is 15A 5V. You can find it in near PC store.